# Refactoring database tables to have a common "base" table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

In my database I have some tables that looks something like:

```
table1
---------------
id  name


table2
---------
id  name  ParnetId     <-This is an ID from Table 1



table3
---------------
id  name  ParnetId     <-This is an ID from Table 2
```

In the past, It seemed that the three tables are completely separate entities but now (due to a new requested feature...) I need to reference from another table any of the three tables.
Something like:

```
table4
---------------
id  name  foreignKey   <-This ID should be from Table 1 OR Table 2 OR Table 3
```

So, I figured I could add a table that will hold the Id's for tables 1-3 and reference it from the table 4 (+ from tables 1-3 for the Id column).

Please note that I am working on a live database that already contains data.

**My questions are:**

1. Is there anything I need to watch out while performing the refactoring process?
2. How would I migrate the existing records id's from tables 1-3 to table 4 (relating to identical id's in the three tables)?
3. Is there a better strategy you can think of?

Comment: How would you know whether `foreignKey` referenced Table 1, 2, or 3 though? At a minimum I think you'll need another column to indicate the source table.

Comment: @StephenByrne You are correct. I did write it down because I did not think it added valuable information to the question...

Comment: Fair enough, except I believe it's pretty important in this case. But anyway, unless the number of tables can grow, I would recommend just having explicit columns (Table1ID, Table2ID, etc) since it will avoid any confusion when looking at Table4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new table (eg. CommonTable) with its own primary key, with nullable fields as foreign keys to table1, table2 and table3 seems like the way to go.

That way table4 can have a single foreign key to CommonTable, which may link to either table1 or table2 or table3.

A second approach would be to create a view (eg. CommonView) over table1, table2 and table3. You would need to concoct a fake primary key for this - perhaps "t1-xxx", "t2-xxx", "t3-xxx" for table1/2/3. I've used this technique as a temporary data migration mechanism, but wouldn't consider it as a long term solution.

A third approach, probably the easiest to implement, is simply to have multiple nullable foreign keys on table4:

table1Id
table2Id
table3Id

I would strongly advise against having a single field which is a foreign key to more than one table. I've seen this in action and it's a nightmare to work with. Think of the future developers confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having 7 tables in total table4, table1, table2, table3, t4t1link, t4t2link and t4t3link.

t4tXlink table should contain the primary keys from table4 and tableX. Thus you can have proper constraints in your database.

If you have just 1 table to contain 3 separate foreignkeys you can not have constraint that disallows values from other 2 columns.

Comment: But wouldn't this bring me back to square one? which table to I reference form table 4? Actually, this is exactly what I am trying to avoid...

Comment: You don't reference to the t1,t2 or t3 from t4. You do joins via the link tables. "select * from t4 inner join t4t1link ... inner join t1 ... where ..."